# loop over the PHP data Returned to jquery AJAX Call

Tags: php, jquery

below is my $.ajax call to php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.sub_menu a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    var txt = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "thegamer.php",
        data:{send_txt: txt},
        success: function(data){
            $('#container').fadeOut('8000', function (){
                $('#container').html(data);
                $('#container').fadeIn('8000');
            });
        }   
    });
});
});
```

my php code

```
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //Fetch rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        echo $row['img'];

        }
}
```

I m getting this output

```
images/man/caps/army-black.pngimages/man/caps/army-brown.pngimages/man/caps/army-grey.pngimages/man/caps/army-lthr.pngimages
```

these are basically image paths now how to loop over them in jquery and fit each image in image tag

any code will be useful

Plz Note I DONT NEED JSON

regards sajid

Comment: http://www.json.org/ and http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Are you saying $row['img'] has multiple image names in it and you need to break them down, or is all you need to do change the echo to add image tags? echo "<image>".$row['img']."</image>";

Comment: @john yes it has multiple image paths displayed in a div at jquery side i want to break them there at jquery end loop over it and fit it int img src='data[0]' /img

Answer (score 3):

JSON is probably your best bet here. In PHP do something like this:

```
$ret = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{
    $ret[] = $row['img'];
}

echo json_encode( $ret );
```

This will output something like the following

```
["image1","image2","image3"]
```

jQuery has a function which can convert this information into a javascript array. So put this code in your success callback.

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

alert( result[1] );
```

---

**EDIT:** A method which does not use JSON

In PHP place each image url on a separate line

```
echo $row['img'], "\n";
```

Then in javascript, split the response by the new line character

```
var result = data.split( "\n" );
```

Comment: sajid, JSON is simply a way of serializing information to a string. It doesn't require any additional frameworks or libraries or anything like that. What is the reason behind not wanting to use JSON?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an approach which does not use JSON

Comment: I M TIRED OF JSON IT RETURN THIS ["images\/man\/caps\/army-black.png","images\/man\/caps\/army-brown.png","images\/man\/caps\/army-grey.png"] when i apply this var result = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

alert( result[1] );
 it doesnt work and gives <!html Doctype> the basic problem is this i need to loop over that data and fit it in img src and apppend it to dom

Comment: sajid, if you are getting "<!DOCTYPE html>" then your PHP script must be writing more information to the browser then just the image urls. Does "thegamer.php" have any other code above the bit you posted?

Comment: working with ur edit 'echo $row['img'], "\n";'                                                                       
success: function(data){
   var result = data.split( "\n" );
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
   $('#container').fadeOut('8000', function (){
        $('#container').html(result[i]);
     $('#container').fadeIn('8000');
   }                                                                           now im  getting this error The requested URL /new/mcaps was not found on this server.

Comment: got ir but now further its not getting printed

Answer (score 0):

simply change your php code:
`if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo ""<img src='".$row['img']."' /><br />";
  }  }
```